# Fancybox and document.ready

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox, href, document-ready

I have a problem with the fancybox and the `document.ready`. I want that the fancybox starts right after the document is loaded, but for some reason it doesn't work properly. I have tried several things, I always end with the same result.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxHeight: 400,
        maxWidth: 600,

        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: true,
        width: '70%',
        height: '70%',
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        scrolling: 'auto',
    });
});
</script>

<a class="various" href="#inline">Inline</a>
<p> Test </p
```

The fancybox only appears if I click on the href link of "inline". How can I get it working that it pops up when the site is loaded?

I'm a noob in first place, so don't harass me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typo missing `$` sign `$(document)` .

Comment: *The fancybox only appears if you click on the href link of "inline".* that's how the plugin is supposed to work. If you want to trigger the click event, you can do that with `$(theelement).click()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that.

Try

```
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxHeight: 400,
    maxWidth: 600,

    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: true,
    width: '70%',
    height: '70%',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    scrolling: 'auto',
});

$(".various").click();
```

You want to actually trigger the click.

Note: if the script tag is not placed after the .various you will have to wrap it in document.ready as you did yourself.

Comment: or you could chain it like : `$(".various").fancybox({//options}).trigger("click")`